# Elementary physics course for pure math student

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, reference-request, physical-sciences, teaching

Are there any mathematical departments which present the course "elementary physics" for pure math undergraduate students, separately?

Is there a way to present this course with the most pure mathematical manner?

I remember finding a PDF file, many years ago, titled "Lectures on physics". It was a graduate level lecture, written by a mathematician. In that lecture, one could not find any technical physical words. Instead, it contained only mathematical descriptions of physical systems, for example: Hamiltonian system, symplectic geometry, etc.

Unfortunately I lost that PDF file and cannot find it again. It was a lecture from Michigan university. I do not even remember the name of that author but if I am not mistaken his name was 'Idaglu' (or some thing like this) from Michigan. Can anyone help me find that lecture again?

Is there an undergraduate version of the above graduate level lecture?

Comment: The notes are by Igor Dolgachev and can be accessed here: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/lecturenotes.html

Comment: @MichaelJoyce seems like your comment is an answer :)

Comment: See also the following Math Overflow posts: https://mathoverflow.net/q/4183/2312, https://mathoverflow.net/q/51395/2312, https://mathoverflow.net/q/191609/2312 and perhaps also https://mathoverflow.net/q/215349/2312.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I did not attend any *elementary* physics courses by mathematicians for mathematicians, I did attend a curriculum of courses called "Mathematical Physics" held by mathematicians for mathematicians and physicists. In terms of physics and mathematics, they were some kind of advanced level course - it helped if you knew linear algebra, calculus and the basic concepts of theoretical physics. The courses were:

1. Classical Mechanics (including geometrical aspects, dynamical systems and Hamiltonian and Lagrangian mechanics). The lecture notes (in German) can be found [here](http://www.physikmethoden.de/uploads/1/1/0/9/11093021/mechanik_knauf_seiler.pdf).
2. Statistical Mechanics (including topics like entropy and phase transitions). The lecture notes (in German) can be found [here](https://www.studium.math.fau.de/fileadmin/min/users/knauf/Skripte/mp2_script.pdf).
3. Quantum Theory/Operator Theory for Hilbert spaces: Based on the books by Reed/Simon, this was a 1.5-year course providing all the important tools for quantum mechanics and dipping into some interesting aspects of quantum mechanics.
4. Quantum Information Theory. There are preliminary lecture notes by A. Knauf in German, which I'm not going to link here.

Comment: The first link appears to be broken, but Knauf has written a book published by Springer: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662557723

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in Brian C. Hall's book [Quantum Theory for Mathematicians](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/146147115X). The author writes on his [webpage](https://www3.nd.edu/~bhall/book/quantum.html) about the book:

> This book aspires to be a self-contained and reasonably comprehensive treatment of quantum mechanics (excluding quantum field theory) from a mathematical perspective. No prior knowledge of physics is required, but only the basics of Hilbert spaces and real analysis.

See https://www3.nd.edu/~bhall/book/quantum.html for more information. There's also a helpful, detailed [review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3Q509T6Z13W5G/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=146147115X) on Amazon.

Comment: Thank you  very much for your  answer.

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by Michael Joyce:

> The notes are by Igor Dolgachev and can be accessed here: http://math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/lecturenotes.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your  answer and refreshment of Michael' s  comment.  Of course the answer form of this  link help more people. Because some times SE participants do not check comments carefully but they read the answers.  Thanks  again for  your attention to my question.

Answer (score 2):

See Michael Spivak's "[Physics for Mathematicians](http://mathpop.com/)"

See also the [notes that the book came from](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~shifrin/Spivak_physics.pdf)